# Update primary key in the whole database

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

Good morning,

Following a major change in my company, it was decided to change the entire organization of grades.

Currently, our grades are represented in the database by 3 digit identifiers and will be modified by new grades.

for example:

- SEN => ABC
- MGR => JKE
- PDG => 007
- CEO => SOP

As it is identifier, are used (and displayed) in applications, one must replace them by the new ones.
Do you have any idea how I could replace these values in the whole database? 
The DB is in SQL server, and ids are use for a lot of foreign key

Thanks

Comment: You are looking at primary key update cascade. Refer [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84434/cascade-primary-key-update-to-all-referencing-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate all your foreign keys with ON UPDATE CASCADE , then only if you update you primary key , it will update same in foreign key as well.